# modbus-tk getting Modbus Error: Exception code = 2

Tags: python-3.x, modbus-tcp, modbus-tk

I am using modbus-tk for simulate modbus device for unittest.

I am added 2 block data.

```
def add_test_1(self):
    point = "Test_1"
    addr = 40003
    self.slave_1.add_block(point, mbdefines.HOLDING_REGISTERS, addr, 1)
    self.slave_1.set_values(point, addr, 5)

def add_test_2(self):
    point = "Test_2"
    addr = 40004
    self.slave_1.add_block(point, mbdefines.HOLDING_REGISTERS, addr, 2)
    self.slave_1.set_values(point, addr, (16560, 0))
```

But when I use modbus-tk for reading multi register.

```
result = modbus_client.execute(1, mbdefines.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 40003, 3)
print(result)
```

The exception is raised.

`Modbus Error: Exception code = 2`

Meanwhile, I still can read multi data in real Modbus device by using this

```
result = modbus_client.execute(1, mbdefines.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 40003, 3)
print(result)
```

With data look like block data I show it before

I'm using python 3.7.3 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create two different blocks.

```
def add_test_1(self):
    point = "Test_1"
    addr = 40003
    self.slave_1.add_block(point, mbdefines.HOLDING_REGISTERS, addr, 1)
    self.slave_1.set_values(point, addr, 5)

def add_test_2(self):
    point = "Test_2"
    addr = 40004
    self.slave_1.add_block(point, mbdefines.HOLDING_REGISTERS, addr, 2)
    self.slave_1.set_values(point, addr, (16560, 0))
```

Both block can be read, but with two different commands:

```
result_test_1 = modbus_client.execute(1, mbdefines.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 40003, 1)
print(result_test_1 )
# (5, )

result_test_2 = modbus_client.execute(1, mbdefines.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 40004, 2)
print(result_test_2 )
# (16560, 0, )
```

You can also create a single block and read it:

```
def add_test():
    point = "Test_1"
    addr = 40003
    slave_1.add_block(point, cst.HOLDING_REGISTERS, addr, 3)
    slave_1.set_values(point, addr, (5, 16560, 0))

result_test = modbus_client.execute(1, mbdefines.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 40003, 3)
print(result_test)
# (5, 16560, 0, )
```

As you can see on github there is a function called [`_get_block_and_offset`](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/14c70f2c3c794b7e2944762f408b98e7bc77a8fe/modbus_tk/modbus.py#L423) that is called by [`_read_registers`](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/14c70f2c3c794b7e2944762f408b98e7bc77a8fe/modbus_tk/modbus.py#L480). When you read from your slave the server call the function [`_read_holding_registers`](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/14c70f2c3c794b7e2944762f408b98e7bc77a8fe/modbus_tk/modbus.py#L503) that return the result of `_read_registers`, but when it reach the call to [`_get_block_and_offset`](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/14c70f2c3c794b7e2944762f408b98e7bc77a8fe/modbus_tk/modbus.py#L490) it raise [`ModbusError(defines.ILLEGAL_DATA_ADDRESS)`](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/14c70f2c3c794b7e2944762f408b98e7bc77a8fe/modbus_tk/modbus.py#L430) because the conditions `address >= block.starting_address` and `block.size >= offset + length` are not satisfied, so the `return block, offset` is never reached.